# Toggle Table Rows on Click

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have an HTML table, where if you click on the first cell that says "Open", for each row, it will display a child row if it has one. This is working fine, but the only problem is that when I click on the first cell to toggle the child row, all child rows in the table are toggled at the same time. I want it to just display the child row for the row I clicked on, not every single child row. Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kr967kd6/

As you can see in my fiddle, I put the checkbox before the table. I tried putting my checkbox here before:

```
<input id="child1" type="checkbox">
<tr class="toggle">
    <td></td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
</tr>
```

But that will not work. The only way I was able to get these rows to toggle at all was to put the checkbox before the `<table>` element and call it in my CSS like this:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ table tr.toggle { display: table-row; width: calc(100% - 20px); }
```

How can I get the child row to toggle for the corresponding row that I clicked on without all child rows being toggled at the same time?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Use JavaScript

That's cause when ANY checkbox becomes `:checked` you target ALL the TR elements

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ table tr.toggle { /* All TR? nope. wrong. */
```

using your inputs one after the other you can also get stuck in tricky combinations of checked/unchecked. You should place your Checkboxes distant from each-other -> above the needed elements to be targeted using Next Sibling which need to be toggled **(impossible using TABLE)**.

**Use multiple tables instead, or use JS *[or jQuery <sup>jsBin demo</sup>](http://jsbin.com/labaho/3/edit?html,css,js,output)***

```
$(".test-table td a").click(function(){
  $(this).closest("tr").next().toggle();
});
```

---

## Alternative using plain HTML, CSS

The **best** you can do using **plain HTML / CSS** is using the `:target` **selector**
(that won't allow you to toggle or keep the active state, but it's quite useful anyway)

```
.toggle        { display: none; }
.toggle:target { display: table-row; }
```

```
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#tr1">Open</a></td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr1" class="toggle">
        <td></td>
        <td>data</td>
    </tr>
```

***[jsBin demo (using :target selector)](http://jsbin.com/labaho/2/edit?html,css,js,output)***

Comment: I tried putting the checkboxes above the needed elements, but it wouldn't work (it wouldn't toggle the elements) unless I put the child row inside a new table, as you suggested. That worked, however, the child row would lose its styling (it didn't match the original table's styling)

Comment: @developer-x I did not suggested anything silly. You CANNOT put checkboxes inside a table if not inside TD or TH (Which would logically not work since than you cannot go for the next sibling operator.). As I've said use multiple tables or use JavaScript

Comment: @developer-x also, sadly, you cannot use CSS to target Parent elements. So your best game would be using a bit of JS or jQuery.

Comment: This works! I decided to go with the plain HTML/CSS option. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kr967kd6/1/) I have that hopefully will help.

If you don't mind a jQuery solution:

```
$("#data tr td").on("click", function() {
    $(this).parent().next("tr").toggleClass("active");
});
```

And in your CSS, change this:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked table ~ tr.toggle { 
    display: table-row; 
    width: calc(100% - 20px); 
}
```

To this:

```
.toggle.active {
    display: table-row; 
    /* width: calc(100% - 20px);   => As Roko C. Buljan pointed out, width has no effect on <tr> */
}
```

Comment: After testing it out right now, it apparently does not. I was just copying the code in relation to the asker's question, but I am going to remove width from the `.toggle` class since it does not have any effect on the `<tr>` element. Good catch, I just learned something, too!

Comment: Thank you for your help @user1852651